# How to calculating time difference for timezone in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to see if the current time is after noon (lunch).

```
  noon_time = Time.parse "12:00 pm"
  current_time = Time.now
  if current_time < noon_time
    #eat a big meal or sleep its after lunch time
  else
    #work hard its not time to eat
  end
```

When I run this code at 9:38pm it says "eat a big meal".

Do I need to do something like this and capture the time that is set for my website by the user?

```
  offset = Time.now.in_time_zone(current_user.time_zone).gmt_offset/60/60
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try parsing the time from the perspective of the user:

```
Time.zone(current_user.time_zone).parse("12:00pm")
```

If you use `Time.now` you're using it in the default time zone which is, presumably, UTC. It might be a good idea make a wrapper method `time_current` for your User model that returns the time in the correct time zone? The offset itself in isolation is not meaningful.

You could also do the same thing with `time_parse` and then your code would look like:

```
if current_user.time_current >= current_user.time_parse("12:00pm")
  # ... Lunch time!
end
```

Or more succinctly:

```
if current_user.time_current.hour >= 12
  # ... Lunch time!
end
```